# Python CSV Reader adding more items than it should

Tags: python, csv

So i was trying to read a csv file but for some reason it is adding extra items. This is the code of the function that I am using.

```
reader=csv.reader(input_file)
dict,temp={},{}
next(reader)    
for line in reader:
    print(line)
    temp[line[63]]=[line[34],line[4]]

    print (temp)
```

This is the output that I am getting.
[Commmand line output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWzOX.png)

Thank you.

Comment: It looks normal. What output are you expecting? It's not adding `'1984': ['37', '31']` mutiple times, it's just that that key is left unchanged for a long time so it gets printed out repeatedly.

Comment: Ohhh.. What I want is for each to have just single dictionary entries. Like the first few lines of the output. Also, why is it being random, I mean in the first run it is giving 37 constantly in the first index and in the second run is giving 37 in the second index. @AlexHall

Comment: I don't think you understand dictionaries. There can only be one entry for `'1984'`, so it keeps getting replaced. And there's no first or second entry, the way it's displayed is essentially random.